# Can I delay the a4j:commandButton 's action when using accesskey to click it?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have  a `h:inputText` which will calls a back-end method when the onchange() event occurs ,

```
<h:inputText>
    <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{mBean.onInputChange}" />
 </h:inputText>
```

and I have a a4j:commandButton which will do the saving process . The  a4j:commandButton  also has the hot key assigned to it

```
<a4j:commandButton  accesskey="s"   action="#{mBean.performSave}" />
```

When I types text in the `h:inputText` , then pressing "Alt+s" to click the button , both `mBean.performSave()` and `mBean.onInputChange()` will run at the same time . Can I delay the action of `mBean.performSave()`  such that `mBean.performSave()`  will run after `mBean.onInputChange()` complete?

Answer (score 1):

`Richfaces` provides a [`<a4j:queue>`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/queue.jsf) components that could be useful to handle your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a [`<a4j:queue>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_queue.html)